# Why my goldfish red cap lost its head color?

Tags: fish, goldfish, biology

Is it normal that the color fading away..?

The water seems fine.
Food : Tetra Goldfish Growth and other pellet.
It's been 2 months with me.

[image]

Comment: i wish the OP had posted the water parameters in the tank mainly,ammonia-nitrite-PH and the temperature.this information can be used to diagnose the different problems quickly so a potential treatment can be started.colored fish in the carp family are known to change color temporarily if there is a quick change in the PH or if the fish are under stress from poor waterquality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have bought an oranda or could be a lionhead goldfish. Both types of goldfish. I'm pretty sure it's an oranda but can't tell with that picture. So yes, it is normal.

The other one looks like a telescope goldfish so it seems you have many varieties.

Enjoy your tank !

Comment: It is normal? What process is it? Will the color go back?

Comment: how's the lightning? how much color had it ? I thought you were talking the head form not it's color.

Comment: I used LEDs light, the color dissapeared,  at first bought it was red

Comment: You should improve your lightning then. There is an association between bad lightning condition and decolouring on goldfishes. It's not just about strength of the light but also the color. Red lamps are good but you need that color to stay during time.

Comment: I meant, I don't know if its because of light, cuz i used the same light since the first day, you meant i have to buy red light?

Comment: Yes, I do. Red light for tanks are the most similar regarding natural light.

Comment: Do you mean any led light that emits red color?

Comment: It's warm red, there is specific lights for fish tanks with red spectrum that you can buy. In case of led look for RGB ones. There is also full spectrum lights, in other words many colors. https://www.amazon.com/Red-Aquarium-Lights/s?k=Red+Aquarium+Lights

Comment: Maybe put it ourdoor will help?

Comment: Please don't do that, you will stress your fishes more than needed.